# OpenCV CUDA API very slow at the first call

Tags: opencv, cuda

I am using `cuda::resize` to resize a vector of images (in GpuMat)

It shows the first call takes ~15ms, and the rests only take ~0.3ms. So I want to ask if there are ways to shorten the time of the first call.

Here is my code(simplified):

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_images; ++i)
    {
        full_img = v_GpuMat[i].clone(); // vGpuMat is vector of images in cuda::GpuMat
        seam_scale = 0.4377;
        cuda::resize(full_img, img, Size(), seam_scale, seam_scale, INTER_LINEAR);
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: opencv cuda initialization could be slow, show more code about initialization?https://answers.opencv.org/question/40258/gpu-cuda-initialization-much-slower-with-opencv-libraries/

Comment: @flankechen thanks for your reply, I just upload images to GpuMat and use OpenCV APIs. According to the [https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#initialization] it may be the "cuda context" runtime. Also, I think it may be a gpu power management problem.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA device memory allocations and copying data from device to host and vice versa are very slow. Please try allocale memory and load data outside the main loop. Cloning matrix allocates new device memory each time, try to use copying data instead of cloning it should speed up your code.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the result in Nvidia-Visual-Profile, I found it is the **cudaLaunchKernel** that takes ~20ms and will be called only the first time.

[image: NVPP Screenshot]

If you have to make a continuous process like me, maybe one of the solution can be a dry run before you process your own tasks. As for this sample, make a `cuda::resize` out of the loop is much faster.

Comment: could you  comment a bit on this Nvidia Visual Profile